# Is the indefinite integral of a function meaningless on its own?

Tags: calculus, integration

I mean to say does the function F(x), the antiderivative of f (x) have any sort of meaning if you're not taking the difference of it between two limits a and b.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it as the *set* of functions whose derivative is $f$. Any two functions in the set differ by a constant, and have the same difference between $a$ and $b$. Anything said about "the" indefinite integral of $f$" is (or should be!) true of every member of this set. If $f$ is defined on $[a,b]$ then $\int_a^x f(t)\rm{d}t$ is the canonical representative of the set.

An analogy might be "big O" notation: "$f = O(g)$" really means $f\in O(g)$.

Comment: But what if F(0) is nonzero?

Comment: Well, some specific antiderivative $F$ of $f$ will be such that $F(0)\ne 0$, but not all of them are, so you can't say that this is true of "the" indefinite integral (all antiderivatives of $f$).